# Divide graphics window with lines and tell which sprites is on which side

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, 2d-games

I have a large window in which I display graphics in the form of sprites. I have a problem which I need to deal with:

Suppose I want to draw a "wall" in this window. The wall may only consist of vertical and horizontal lines. For instance, a wall may look like a "staircase", but it could also look like the characters "L" "|" "_". Suppose this wall's ends (both start and finish) are connected to either a wall or the edge of the graphics window.

Now, I want to tell which sprite is on which side of this wall. Every time I divide the window with a wall I want to be able to tell which sprite ended up on which side.

Is there an algorithm or method I could use to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

**Vector Cross Product to find which side a point is**

To tell is a point is left or right of a line you get the cross product of line and point. You need to translate the line so that its start is at the origin, and equally move the point. Then get the cross product and if the value is negative then the point is to the left (in an anticlockwise direction) if the value is 0 then the point is on the line, and if the value is positive then the point is to the right (in a clock wise direction) of the line.

Thus a line

```
x1 = 100;  // line start coord
y1 = 100;
x2 = 300;  // line end coord
y2 = 300; 

px = 300;  // the point to test
py = 100; 

// first translate the line and point so that the line start is at 0,0
px = px - x1;
py = py - y1;
x2 = x2 - x1; // no need to move the start as dont need it after translation
y2 = y2 - y1;

// And now just the cross product

cross = x2 * py - y2 * px;
if(cross < 0){ // point is left of line
if(cross > 0){ // point is right of line
else { // point is on the line
```

That is easy to adapt to a sprite by doing each corner in turn. If at any point you find a point on the other side than any previous points you know that the sprite is on the line and can forgo any further testing.

For more on the cross product see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the x and y co-ordinates of the sprite rect and just use greater than and less than for the horizontal and vertical walls. Give the Sprite a rect as detailed here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite and set the rect.x and rect.y attributes and use them to position the sprite.

For a diagonal wall you would have to test both x and y to see which side is it on.